# Re-use of items used in service of another deity upon conversion

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, avodah-zarah, tznius-modesty, hair-covering

I am in the process of converting to Judaism from being a hellenic pagan (yes, there is a small revivalist movement, and yes, I am deeply grateful I was led away from that path) and I had a specific question about transferable practices and items.

As part of my former path, I had covered my hair for years, and adopted a much more modest dress code. Although this practice is actually part of what led me away from paganism, I am concerned about how to fulfill the modesty requirements if I initially adopted the practice in service to another god. Since committing to the conversion process, I have stopped covering my hair out of respect because I did not want there to be any confusion about why I was doing it (either for myself or for others). I would, however, like to resume modest dress including hair covering if possible. Can I resume the practice, and if so, when? Also, what is the status of the scarves I used to cover with?

So far, I have found information on items used as sacrifices to idols, but that is the closest I've come to finding an answer. My difficulty here is that the scarves themselves were never used as sacrifices, but rather as part of a duty. They are still perfectly usable and in good condition, and they were never "given," so to speak. I also never had a physical rendering of an idol at any point (I am not sure that matters, but mention it in case that distinction does matter.)

Would it be permissible to use them, and if so, what would I need to do to them, if anything? If not, what would be the most appropriate thing to do with them?

**Edit:** Background information--

Here is a link that explains some of the background of it: http://lady-magique-et-lady-chance.tumblr.com/post/145507542051/veiling-and-binding. I avoided too much description here because I wasn't sure if giving that kind of detail would be problematic. As you'll see from the link, it was related to hair binding, and so if I should get rid of my scarves, I should honestly get rid of my hair ties as well. The scarves themselves weren't specially designed for the purpose, contained no unique imagery or symbols, and were not offerings. I chose scarves over simple braids because I liked the added privacy and because it was specifically a devotion to Hestia (modesty is one of her attributes): http://www.theoi.com/Ouranios/Hestia.html.

Comment: Your title is at variance with the content of your question. The title says " items used **in service of another deity** upon conversion". The content says "My difficulty here is that the scarves themselves were never used as sacrifices, but rather as part of a duty." See my comment to MortyV's answer. Please clarify if the scarves were used in service of the avodah zoroh or just as clothing to be modest.

Comment: I'm really sorry; I'm not sure if I can answer that correctly. I took up dressing much more modestly as a devotion, but the scarves were never offered up. The act was the offering, not the items. Does that clarify it? If not I can try to explain further . . . Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Hi Rachael and welcome to Mi Yodeya! I hope you enjoy your stay here, and I'm sure the mods will be around soon to give you the full welcome treatment. In the meantime, I'd like to underscore that you should "[treat information you find here as if it came from a crowd of your friends](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)," and you should [see whichever Rav is helping you with your conversion](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146) for specific details for your circumstances.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Rachel! If you don's mind, consider adding in a basic description of the relationship of the practice of hair covering, to the idea(s) of paganism. (or add a link). Better understanding of the role of the scarf; particularly for those with very little background knowledge of paganism would be useful. [Hatslacha Rabbah](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4120/8775).

Comment: If you are currently single, then you can leave your hair uncovered until you are married. That would show the difference.

Comment: Thank you Rachael for this very interesting question and much success on your  journey to faith. There are many elements monotheistic and even pagan  faiths have in common. Turning an act of earthliness  into holy sounds like a remarkable accomplishment. Modesty in dress is not exclusive to Judaism and only those misinformed would assume it foreign to paganism. I would have to believe you have already turned the act of modesty into holy even though it's the same act. The clothing? Is it possible you purified the clothing by changing the acts intent?

Comment: I am reminded of the old Indian Hair wig question. It seems the largest source of hair for wigs in a texture similar to that of most married Jewish Women is from the Tirupati temple in India. The question is re-asked with each generation. In the most recent iteration, they asked Dr Alan Morinis, head of the Mussar Institute who in a previous life was a Rhodes Scholar (ie Oxford) who wrote a PhD in Hindu Pilgrimages. Dr Morinis explained that the point of the haircut is not a sacrifice of hair, but to give up one's appearance and vanity. (C.f. Nazir?) And on those grounds, it was permitted.

Comment: Also a distinction between things done as part of the religion, and actual sacrifices to a god.

On a more personal note, I am happy you found satisfaction for your thirst for meaning. Now, if you need a family with which to enjoy a Shabbos, and are in the greater NY area, please contact me privately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The OP asks if it is proper to continue to adhere to a lifestyle of modest custom (women's dress code; specifically: covering the hair) even though she once did so as a duty to a false god. (revivalist Hellenic Paganism)
2. The OP then asks about being allowed to keep/use scarves which were once used to cover her hair, in these practices of modesty, in service to a false god. (as above)

2b. The OP (Rachael) is currently converting to Judaism. Welcome, much success!:)

Answer to # 1 :

Although the Torah says: "..."Do not follow any of their (Gentile) traditions" (Leviticus 18:3), that is only where the custom is irrational, specifically rooted in Gentile religion, or is forbidden or deemed immoral by the Torah. However, if the Gentile practice is rational (eat healthy etc.) it is permitted to copy them. (see Rav Sampson Raphael Hirsch; Horeb 505.)

The Rambam generally explains this Mitzvah as an obligation for the Jew to be distinct and separate from the nations in our dress, and actions. Everyone should distinctly be able to tell we are Jews. (Hilchos A"Z 11:1)

Therefore: We must act as Jews and may (should) do rational things. The fact that some Gentiles also act rationally and correctly in their behavior as human beings does not force us to change. Just the opposite is true. We hope that all the nations of the world should be righteous and live rationally and correctly according to Torah values! Jews are after all, a light unto the nations.

If so, a Jewish woman (and practicing convert to Judaism) should dress modestly in the way of "tznius".

Besides, what is the alternative?? Would someone specifically suggest that Jewish women wear bikinis and mini-skirts, because some Gentiles suddenly decided to dress modestly??!! That would obviously be ridiculous!

Revivalist Hellenic Paganism actually has no book of law or text of tradition. The general concept they have is to adhere to "piety". This is generally described as repaying kindness, having guests, and living in moderation etc. These are simply rational ideas sometimes taken from the Torah; or just described as "being a good person". The only mistake is that these Pagans believe these life rules to be the will of many gods who live on Mt. Olympus etc.

The idea of being "good" or "modest" is not disqualified simply because these misguided people think "the gods" said so. :)

As far as covering one's hair: Jewish women usually do not cover their hair if they are single. Married women do so.

In any case, the general rule is: If it is general modesty, or Jewish tznius code, then it is obviously OK even if idolaters also do this. If it is a very specific way in modest dress, that is noticeably peculiar to a sect of idolaters, then a Jew should not imitate it.

Answer to #2 :

Moses told Pharoah that Pharoah would also send sacrifices with the Jews on his behalf when they left Egypt. (Ex. 10:25) This is one source where we see that a Gentile who recants his idolatrous belief, causes the idol to become permissible for use. Otherwise, how could Moses accept animals from Pharoah to sacrifice to G-d? The Egyptians worshiped animals. It must be that Pharoah, realizing that the Jewish G-d was real and his animals were not really gods, nullified the animals' idolatrous status by disbelieving in them. Then he gave them to Moses. At that point they were kosher.

See also Talmud A"Z 64a-b. The Gemara discusses that people who were in the conversion process were advised to sell any idolatrous items before becoming Jews so they could benefit from selling them. This is because converts obviously no longer believed in the false gods, so their idolatrous material was nullified and therefore permitted.(The thing is once they were Jews, they could no longer do this because it would look bad.)

Also, please note: An idol worshipped by a Jew can never be nullified; only an idol worshipped by a Gentile can be nullified.

But, a scarf worn to be modest, is not an idol or an item of idolatry, even if the person practiced modesty for the sake of a false god. So keeping it or selling it is certainly OK.

However, if it is obvious that a piece of clothing is a uniform for that idolatrous group (nun's habit) it shouldn't be worn even if it is "modest" . :)

I hope this helped. As always, consult your conversion Rav. Much Success!

Comment: Great point about rationality and non-incompatibility with Judaism as the tests for whether a Gentile custom can be followed. A world in which nothing invented or developed by a non-Jew could be used would be a very limited one indeed. Take something as simple and useful as the mathematical branch of Algebra (*al-jabr*), something not grounded in any religion and that is universally useful, but invented and developed in the Islamic world.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Thank you Robert. Great point. Although, my kids, who are in high school, may disagree about Algebra being useful. :)

Answer (score -3):

No way can items used for avodah zarah be used in any way, shape, or form. They are regarded as tumah, should be thrown away, and not found in your house. In my opinion, covering your hair should be farther down on your priority list than avodah zarah issues.

Comment: The scarves were not used for avodah zoroh! The OP says "My difficulty here is that the scarves themselves were never used as sacrifices, but rather as part of a duty." The duty was "modest dress".

Comment: OP needs to describe what the scarves were used for.

Comment: Yes. See my comment to the question.

Comment: What is your source that items used for avodah zarah must be thrown away, as opposed to not using them for avodah zarah anymore? Also, can you give a hard source that says "covering your hair should be farther down on your priority list than avodah zarah issues"?

Comment: avodah zarah 13A: The following question was then asked: R. Nathan says: On the day when remission is made of the usual tax towards idolatrous purpose, the proclamation is made: 'Whosoever will take a wreath and put it on his head and on the head of his ass in honour of the idols, his tax will be remitted; otherwise his tax will not be remitted!' How should the Jew act who is present there? Shall he put it on? That means that he is enjoying [the odour of idolatrous articles]! Shall he not put it on? Then he confers a benefit [of paying tax towards idolatry]! Cont.

Comment: I do not think that this answers the question. What she seems to be asking is, would a good practice originally done because of avodas zarah have to be abandoned even though it is supposed to be done as a Jew?

Comment: It's both, actually (although I appreciate the clarification!) I am wondering both about the actual practice (as you described) as well as what I should do with the literal items involved. As a general comment, I'd like to thank everyone for your responses - it is much appreciated.